# HIVE Sql Date conversion

Tags: hive

I have a query that I was asked to modify.

The original field is:  Startdate with a MM/DD/YYYY format.
1/1/2020
In the source table, startdate is a string field.

I was asked to change the format to YYYY-MM-DD (mod_startdate1), but will need a 00:00:00 timestamp included.
2020-01-01

The best i can get to is mod_startdate2, but note that the minute field is replicating the month field
2020-01-01 00:01:00

query used for the screenshot.
select startdate, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(startdate,'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-mm-dd') as mod_startdate1, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(startdate,'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss') as mod_startdate2
from datamart_core.fbp_baseline limit 50
--returns date format, returns timestamp, but the month is also populating as the minutes
HIVE SQL format[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qb3J.jpg)

I'd appreciate any ideas to help resolve my query.  Thank you.

I've found multiple repositories, but have not found 'the' solution yet

Comment: can you pls try `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(startdate||' 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') as dt`